Efficient division by 99 by hand to compute digits of $\pi$
I want to compute some digits of $\pi$ by hand. There are several formula which have been used in pre-computer time, among them:
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4}&=4\arctan(\frac{1}{5})-\arctan(\frac{1}{239})\\
\frac{\pi}{4}&=4\arctan(\frac{1}{5})-\arctan(\frac{1}{70})+\arctan(\frac{1}{99})
\end{align}
The first was used by Machin and Shanks, the second by Rutherford. Both used Gregory's series for the arctangent:
\begin{align}
\arctan x = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}.
\end{align}
In his paper from the year 1841, Rutherford says that

The process employed in these approximations may be greatly simplified by replacing $\arctan(1/239)$ by $\arctan(1/70)-\arctan(1/99)$, inasmuch as the calculation of the terms of the series involving inverse powers of $70$ and $99$ may be effected by arithmetical processes of very great facility. By employing the synthetic process of division by $99$ $(100-1)$ becomes even more simple than that by $9$ or $11$, since it is effected by adding together two numbers each less than $10$.

In the internet, I found indian "vedic mathematic" tricks for divisions by 99, where chunks of two digits are added together - but no method that is as simple as Rutherford described above.
Question: Who knows an an algorithm to divide a many-digit-number by $99$ where only one-digit-numbers have to be added?
Bonus: Maybe also an algorithm for division by $49$ to compute the $\arctan(1/70)$? It may be similar to the one by $99$.

Do you really think that it is worth the time to do that ? Even for , say , $9$ digits , you will need a significant amount of time.

@Peter: I started using Machin's formula which needs about 4 hours for 25 decimals (including double-checking). It was pretty fun! But most of the thime goes into the long divisions by 239²=57121.

I think Rutherford refers to the fact that
$$\frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{100} = 0.00\overline{10}$$
With that in mind, you can express a division by $99$ like this:
$$\frac{x}{99} = \frac{x}{100}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x}{10^{2i+2}}\right)$$
So you just keep adding $x$ shifted by two digits, a simple summation of two numbers less than $10$ when done on paper. Iterate until you hit the decimal digits only.
As for your bonus question: this trick does not work here, because $1/49$ is not even periodic, much less $\overline{01}$-periodic.

I guess it might be periodic in another base.
